# How can I make a display all white for illumination?

Tags: display, backlight

Is it possible to make a specific display all white while still keeping the desktop on another display? The purpose is to illuminate the surroundings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a blank HTML file and opening it in a browser in full screen.

This should suffice:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Save as `white.html` and put the browser window to the screen you want.

Comment: And press `F11`.

Comment: Thanks, makes the whole screen white, and probably the easiest to automate (chromium-browser white.html; xdotool key F11)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `xrandr` command to set gamma or brightness of a specific screen.  For instance,

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 20
```

Alternatively

```
xrandr --output VGA --gamma 20:20:20
```

The number has to be played with since it may depend on your hardware, and general rule of thumb would be setting it to some obscenely large value. In the image below (not the best quality of image, by the way) you can see that the screen combined with a white background of a web page makes the screen almost entirely white.

[image]

Note: the solution is a software approach, meaning that it doesn't have any effect on the power consumption

Comment: AFAIK this would not make any difference when the screen contents are completely white (as other answers suggest).

Comment: @Melebius Making screen contents completely white is one way, sure. Altering  backlight settings is another.  This is Ubuntu site, after all, so it's just one more way to skin the cat, programmatically, and can even be scripted. I mean . . . difference depends on your imagination :)

Comment: IIRC `--brightness` takes a value between 0 and 1, so 20 is like 20x the normal brightness, and to reset to normal, you'd use 1.

Comment: I like my Libre Writer cat... uhh solution much better...

Comment: @muru correct, 1 will reset brightness back to normal. As for values, it can go above 1. Before posting I've tested by incrementing the value higher and higher, and 20 seems to be the point where higher values don't make noticeable difference, hence using that

Comment: @WillemK nothing wrong with liking your own answer :) my solution is better for me, since I have terminal open all the time. Whatever works for you is fine

Comment: I'll probably have to go with a blank html page, but using xrandr to set the brightness will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I got one:  You start Libre Office Writer, set the page layout to landscape, goto full screen mode. This gives you about 85% white screen.  :-)

Comment: My LibreOffice Writer gives me a 100% blank white full screen, but you have to play with the menu buttons and it takes 3-4 steps to get there.

Comment: @karel: perhaps the next question will be how to make the white screen into the shape of a light-bulb....   ;-)